# How to combe multiple text files into one big one?

Tags: windows

I will be working with multiple text files with my friends. I need something that will combine multiple text files into a master file. The method I am after is something that is simple and will create a master file in a click of a button, better if I don't have to install any software (I'm using Windows 7 64bit Professional), simplicity is what I need.

For example in: `C:\mydocs\blah\blah`

I have:

- Hello.txt
- Iloveyou.txt
- Goodbye.txt

I want the master file to combine text inside in that order. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a cmd shell, then

```
type Hello.txt Iloveyou.txt Goodbye.txt >masterfile.txt
```

or

```
copy Hello.txt+Iloveyou.txt+Goodbye.txt masterfile.txt
```

I think it will be simpler if you write a `.bat` to do so.

Comment: +1 for cmd bat file. (I took the liberty of tweaking your formatting).

Comment: bat file? How do I specify the directory of my files? These don't work they seems to be getting an error.

Comment: @FlavorOfLife, you specify the directory with `cd C:\mydocs\blah\blah`. What error did you get?

Comment: Okay, never mind. These two work superbly now... in cmd.exe NOT Powershell (silly me). Might I add type is better than copy as copy adds some character at the end. I've made a .bat file and... I'm a bloody happy SuperUser.

Comment: @FlavorOfLife Congruatlations being super ;)

Answer (score 0):

How important is it that the master aggregate file is updated all the time? If internet connectivity is not a problem, what about using [**Google Docs**](http://docs.google.coM)? I think you can all even edit the master file and the appropriate parts will be merged.

I was thinking along the lines of a simple batch append script, but there are probably more modern ways to do this.

---

**EDIT: I have a wonderful thing. It is called [MobWrite](http://code.google.com/p/google-mobwrite/), and it was developed by [Neal Fraser, GE](http://neil.fraser.name/). The Google Code site has a downloadable standalone version, and you can also create online documents here a la PasteBin.**

In the words of the author,

> MobWrite now has what I believe to be the most advanced cursor preservation algorithm available.

If you are interested in the technical details (and how it compares to Google Docs), please see his write-up here:

http://neil.fraser.name/writing/cursor/

Comment: I think the append script is what I'm after. I might of indulged on too many features on the question...

Comment: I've updated with a handy solution.

Comment: Well, I said you could do a batch append a day before the other answer, but now I see you've edited your question.

Comment: @FlavorOfLife At least give an upvote to all this work, dude.

Answer (score 0):

If these are true TXT files, I would suggest some version control system like Git.  You wouldn't need to split the files, but I'm sure the file is some kind of rich file format like a Word document.

If you are using Word 2010, then you can use Skydrive and everyone can work on the document at once.  [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/video-coauthoring-in-word-2010-VA101848883.aspx?queryid=140d0494423c46c3911d713f6ea76f59&respos=0) is a video on Microsoft Word's CoAuthoring.

Comment: Ahh I have Word 2010 but I never knew that :D, I wouldn't go creating a new sharepoint though as dropbox is already enough to propagate changes that my friend makes.